# Has anyone successfully integrated Ember.js - Phonegap (and jQuery Mobile)?

Tags: ios, cordova, ember.js

I'm struggling to integrate Cordova(=Phonegap) with Ember.js, and jQuery Mobile. Ember.js + jQuery Mobile works fine, as loading index.html in any desktop browser successfully loads the app.

Using xCode 4 and the iPhone 5.1 simulator, it doesn't show any content within handlebar tags. Which means Ember.js fails to load.

**index.html:**

```
<html lang="en"> 
<head>

  <title></title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main">
    this text is NOT displayed

  </script>

  <div> this text IS displayed </div>


  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      // If you want to prevent dragging, uncomment this section
      function preventBehavior(e){ 
          e.preventDefault(); 
      };
      document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);


      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      /* When this function is called, Cordova has been initialized and is ready to roll */
      /* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
      see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
      for more details -jm */
      function onDeviceReady(){
          // do your thing!
      }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. XCode was reporting:

```
 ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css'
```

Following [this](http://www.prosoxi.com/2011/10/08/xcode-phonegap-white-list-rejection/), I added `*.jquery.com` to the `ExternalHosts` array, within `Cordova.plist`.

Comment: I will let you know, your app will be rejected if you are placing your jQuery dependency on network connection. You can use the network, but you need to have things in place to let users know why a part of the app isn't working because they have no connection.

Comment: correction css - same thing though. your app needs to have those kinds of files loaded with it in order to be approved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know that, I was intending to make the app fully available offline though.